# Why does time lapse not work on a Nikon D800?

Tags: timelapse, features, nikon-d800

I've bought a Nikon D800 a month ago. I'm trying to turn on the opportunity for Time lapse photography, but my camera doesn't give me the chance. Is it something to do to unlock this choice?

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend taking a look at the Nikon D800 manual which can be found online [here](http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D800_EN.pdf).

Page 207 of the manual describes the features of the D800 and time lapse photography.
You also will want to pay particular notice to the tips of the bottom of page 209 where it describes what modes time-lapse does not work in.

If you have a question beyond something that the manual already describes then I would come back here and ask it in a new question.

Comment: @matt grum - I agree 100%

Comment: It's a shame stackoverflow has a minimum length for answers as "RTFM" would be more than appropriate :)

Comment: The manual may well not be in his native language (eg may be in English). If Y'All can read his language well enough to follow details in a D800 manual written in it them your comments may be apposite. Or, they may be anyway, but a small amount of leeway may be in order.

Comment: As far as I know, you can not sell device if you don't have user manual on your native language.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - Well if the user can't read the manual due to language constraints, how is asking at this English language site going to help? I am pointing them to the manual, and describing what it says in English in my answer. Just wondering what you think...

Comment: @dpollitt - I think that your input was probably pivotally helpful. Having a small amount of material to work through that has been distilled by an expert is a great start. In particular, your mention of the footnote material on page 209 re where time lapse does not work is probably just what he needs. "bottom of page 209" will probably translate well enough :-). In the past I have dealt with people who speak only Chinese. I speak & write essentially none. Use of a translation program and hours of work and careful phrasing usually works long term. A flesh & blood translator is vastly faster.

Comment: I assume Matt was suggesting he read the French manual.  Otherwise - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23628/how-should-we-deal-with-rtfm-comments

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is set the time/date in the setup menu and it will work.

Comment: Are you sure there are no other conditions where it might be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Using Ctrl+F "lapse" in the [manual](http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D800_EN.pdf) can yield some restrictions of the time lapse function. Those restrictions are usually listed near the function which affects something.
Those restrictions are:

1. HDR on page 176
2. Interval Timer Photography on page 203
3. and other restrictions listed on page 209